# Using an anchor element to remove a label in a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, contenteditable

I have a React app that has a component using react-contentEditable.

in the image I provided, I need to click on the X and remove that label from the html prop in contentEditable component. contentEditable needs a string for its html prop. I need to somehow update the html prop string to a new string that discards the selected label but keeps the others. my first thought was a button, but I couldnt seem to pass an onClick when the html requires a string... so I defaulted to trying a  tag. can an  tag somehow remove or change the class of the clicked element in contentEditable?

In my component I have a "add Contacts" button that when clicked updates the contentEditable html to a string with a `<label> <span> <a> </a> </span> </label>`. I need to figure out how to use an anchor element or maybe a button with some type of onclick to remove the "clicked" element.

in the image I provided, I need to click on the X and remove that label from the html prop in contentEditable component. contentEditable needs a string for its html prop. I need to somehow update the html prop string to a new string that discards the selected label but keeps the others. my first thought was a button, but I couldnt seem to pass an onClick when the html requires a string... so I defaulted to trying a  tag. can an  tag somehow remove or change the class of the clicked element in contentEditable?

```
import React, { createRef, Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const AddContactTo = ({ toFieldRef, recipients, setRecipients, contactsModal, setContactsModal, toField, setToField }) => {

 const addContactsToDiv = () => {
    let selectedContactsArray = [] // create and empty array
    const Matches = selectedRows.filter((row) => {
      const isMatched = contacts.some(contact => { if(contact._id == row) {
        selectedContactsArray.push({firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, phone_number:contact.phone_number, _id: contact._id})
      }})
      return isMatched
    })
    const matchedContactsArray = []
    selectedContactsArray.map(contact => { // mapping over selected to add html 
      matchedContactsArray.push((`
      <label contentEditable="false" class="p-1 font-weight-bold bg-primary ml-2 text-white rounded-capsule shadow-none fs--3">${contact.firstName + " " + contact.lastName + " "}
      <span class="badge fs--1 badge-soft-success badge-pill ml-2">${contact.phone_number}</span>
      <a href="#" class="badge-pill badge-soft-primary">X</a> // when this <a> is clicked, I need to remove only this element from the html
      <span name="indy-contacts" class="d-none">${contact._id}</span>
      </label>`))
    })
    matchedContactsArray.map(contact => { return contact})
     const stringifiedRows = matchedContactsArray.toString()
     setToField({...toField, html: stringifiedRows})
     selectedContactsArray = []
     
  }

export default AddContactTo
```

[image]

Here is the contentEditable div. This is in a parent component
MessageCreateForm.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, Fragment } from 'react';
import ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable';

const MessageCreateForm = () => {

  const toFieldRef = useRef()

  const handleChange = evt => {
   
   console.log(evt.target.value)
   console.log(toField.value)
   console.log(toFieldRef)
   const indyContacts = document.getElementsByName('indy-contacts')
   const indyGroups = document.getElementsByName('indy-groups')
   setToField({html: evt.target.value})
   
};


const handleBlur = (evt) => {
    console.log(toFieldRef.current);
    console.log(evt.target.value)
};

const handleClick = () => {
  console.log(toFieldRef)
}

<ContentEditable
         name="to"
         innerRef={toFieldRef} // passing our ref instead of state
         html={toField.html} // the html = our ref.current property
         //value={toField}
         onBlur={handleBlur}
         onClick={() => {handleClick()}}
         onChange={handleChange} // this sets our refs.current = event.target.value
         style={{minHeight: "7em", maxHeight: "10em", overflow: "auto"}}
         className="border border-2x border-300 bg-light rounded-soft fs-1"
         >
         </ContentEditable>


export default MessageCreateForm;
```

Comment: in the image I provided, I need to click on the X and remove that label from the html prop in contentEditable component. contentEditable needs a string for its html prop.  I need to somehow update the html prop string to a new string that discards the selected label but keeps the others. my first thought was a button, but I couldnt seem to pass an onClick when the html requires a string... so I defaulted to trying a <a> tag. can an <a> tag somehow remove or change the class of the clicked element in contentEditable?

Comment: All that belongs in your question, not down here. :)